# How to list users who are counted towards the Crowd License using Rest API

Tags: atlassian-crowd

Requirement: I need to derive no of users who are counted towards license for Crowd.

Apps structure in crowd:

Currently we have 2 applications defined in crowd namely App1 & App2.

Also we have 2 directories created as well, dir1 and dir2.

Both the directories are mapped to both the applications in the same order.

Now I have created two groups "grp1" & "grp2", one in each directory respectively and added some users in each group.

Now in "Who can authenticate" section of "app1", I have mapped "grp1" under

"dir1" and under "dir2", "grp2" has been mapped.

The same goes for "app2" as well, in "who can authenticate" section for "app2", I have mapped grp1" under "dir1" and under "dir2", "grp2" has been mapped.

Now I need to fetch the no of users who are counted towards license from the above setup using rest API's.

Can anyone list out any Rest end point available in crowd for achieving this requirement or maybe can even point out the approach to be used using the existing crowd Rest Api's.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Given the logic of how many users count towards your Crowd license should be - the sum of the distinct users (by the field mapped as username in your directories) in both grp1 and grp2, the REST endpoints you'd likely need are:

/rest/usermanagement/1/group/child-group/direct?groupname=grp1
/rest/usermanagement/1/group/child-group/direct?groupname=grp2

If group nesting is enabled/used, then you'll also want:

/rest/usermanagement/1/group/child-group/nested?groupname=grp1
/rest/usermanagement/1/group/child-group/nested?groupname=grp2

Get users from both, merge and de-dupe.

Refs:
 - https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/crowd#serverlicenses-5
 - https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/3.3.0/REST/#usermanagement/1/group

CCM